# SQL Sum amount spent by specific code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that lists all vendors and when I paid them. I'd like to SUM the total amount paid per vendor. Currently, a specific vendor may have 25 rows, being paid on different dates for different amounts. I just wanna show one row, for each vendor_code, vendor name, and the total amount paid to them.

So far I have this:

```
select s.vendor_code, 
       a.address_name, 
       a.addr2, a.addr3, 
       a.city, a.state, 
       a.postal_code, a.vend_class_code, 
       date_applied, SUM(amt_net) as 'Total'
from appyhdr_all s, apmaster a
where s.vendor_code = a.vendor_code
  and s.pay_to_code = a.pay_to_code
  and void_flag=0
  and s.payment_type <> 4
```

currently, I am getting this error: `Column 'appyhdr_all.vendor_code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: HINT: You need use `GROUP BY` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: What table is vendor and what is sales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
select s.vendor_code 
       , a.address_name 
       , a.addr2
       , a.addr3 
       , a.city
       , a.state 
       , a.postal_code
       , a.vend_class_code 
       , SUM(amt_net) as 'Total'
from    appyhdr_all s
join    apmaster a
        on s.vendor_code = a.vendor_code
where   1 = 1
    and s.pay_to_code = a.pay_to_code
    and void_flag=0
    and s.payment_type <> 4
group 
by      s.vendor_code 
       , a.address_name 
       , a.addr2
       , a.addr3 
       , a.city
       , a.state 
       , a.postal_code
       , a.vend_class_code
```

Comment: No its not, look again ;)

Comment: @anve is there a reason you didn't accept my response as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should to include a `group by` clause and put there all selected non aggregated attributes:

```
select s.vendor_code, 
       a.address_name, 
       a.addr2, a.addr3, 
       a.city, a.state, 
       a.postal_code, a.vend_class_code, 
       date_applied, SUM(amt_net) as 'Total'
from appyhdr_all s, apmaster a
where s.vendor_code = a.vendor_code
  and s.pay_to_code = a.pay_to_code
  and void_flag=0
  and s.payment_type <> 4
group by s.vendor_code,       --<--here it is 
       a.address_name, 
       a.addr2, a.addr3, 
       a.city, a.state, 
       a.postal_code, a.vend_class_code, 
       date_applied
```

By the way, may be you want to move your most recent join syntax:

```
...
from appyhdr_all s
inner join apmaster a
    on s.vendor_code = a.vendor_code
   and s.pay_to_code = a.pay_to_code
where void_flag=0
...
```

**Edited** due OP comment:

*"When I implement that, I still get multiple rows of the same vendor code."*

That means you have several rows on apmaster for each vendor. You must to decide witch `apmaster` row you take for each vendor. This is the total for each vendor:

```
with total_by_vendor as (
 select s.vendor_code, SUM(amt_net) as 'Total'
 from appyhdr_all s inner join apmaster a
    on s.vendor_code = a.vendor_code
   and s.pay_to_code = a.pay_to_code
 where void_flag=0
   and s.payment_type <> 4
 group by s.vendor_code
)
select *
from total_by_vendor;
```

Just join it with most recent data on apmaster:

```
with total_by_vendor as (
 select s.vendor_code, SUM(amt_net) as 'Total'
 from appyhdr_all s inner join apmaster a
    on s.vendor_code = a.vendor_code
   and s.pay_to_code = a.pay_to_code
 where void_flag=0
   and s.payment_type <> 4
 group by s.vendor_code
),
recent_apmaster as (
 select vendor_code, a.address_name, 
       a.addr2, a.addr3, 
       a.city, a.state, 
       a.postal_code, a.vend_class_code,
       row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY vendor_code 
                           ORDER BY a.address_name desc ) --put here criteria
       as n
 from apmaster a
)
select *
from total_by_vendor T inner join recent_apmaster a
  on T.vendor_code = a.vendor_code
where n = 1;
```

Comment: @Thanks so much. When I implement that, I still get multiple rows of the same vendor code. What I am looking for is, one row for each vendor code, listing the total amount `(amt_net)` paid to that vendor. Vendor code looks like `V001`. With that code, I am getting almost 101,000 rows back.

Comment: @anve, I just elaborated my answer, I don't know if you can understand it. Read it for twice and set it to your scenario. Regards.

Comment: The reason he is getting multiple values is because you left in the "date_applied" field.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using aggregate functions:

> SUM(amt_net) as 'Total'

Make sure a column appear in the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0):

try something simpler first. if `appyhdr_all s` is vendor this should work.

```
select s.vendor_code, 
       SUM(amt_net) as 'Total'
from appyhdr_all s
inner join apmaster a
    on s.vendor_code = a.vendor_code
   and s.pay_to_code = a.pay_to_code
where void_flag=0
and s.payment_type <> 4
group by s.vendor_code
```